# Filtro SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tenho um exercício pra fazer mas estou quebrando a cabeça aqui:

"Comando SQL que me traga a soma dos salários recebidos por colaborador e estado no ano de 2014 das tabelas: SALARIOS / COLABORADORES / LOCAL_DE_TRABALHO".

Já criei e preenchi todas as tabelas, agora estou tentando fazer a consulta.

```
SELECT SUM(VALOR_PAGO) as total_pago, NOME_COLABORADOR as colaborador,
       DATA_PAGAMENTO as Data_pagamento
from COLABORADORES   Inner join SALARIO
on SALARIO.ID_COLABORADOR = COLABORADORES.ID_COLABORADOR 
WHERE YEAR(DATA_PAGAMENTO) = 2014
```

Erro:

> A coluna 'COLABORADORES.NOME_COLABORADOR' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: faltou o GroupBy? não é isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa uma [função de agregação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173454(v=sql.120).aspx) dessa maneira (nesse exemplo o [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187810(v=sql.120).aspx)) você precisa especificar quais são os critérios do agrupamento para mostrar no resultado.

No seu caso, você quer a **soma** do `valor_pago` **por colaborador**. O critério de seleção é o ano da data de pagamento, mas se quiser exibí-lo no resultset também, ele terá que fazer parte do agrupamento e como ano mesmo, senão o resultado mostrará uma soma para cada date de pagamento.

Então, sua consulta deveria ficar assim:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(valor_pago) AS total_pago, 
    nome_colaborador AS colaborador, 
    YEAR(data_pagamento) AS ano_data_pagamento
FROM colaboradores 
    INNER JOIN salario ON salario.id_colaborador = colaboradores.id_colaborador
WHERE 
    YEAR(data_pagamento) = 2014
GROUP BY 
    nome_colaborador, 
    YEAR(data_pagemento)
```

Comment: Obrigada isso me ajudou bastante.